# Как найти, является ли список подсписком другого списка?

Tags: oracle, plsql, коллекции

Хочу найти, является ли список подсписком другого списка.

Это фрагмент кода процедуры:

```
TYPE TYPE_LIST IS TABLE OF VARCHAR(200);
CHILD_ITEMS TYPE_LIST;
PARENT_ITEMS TYPE_LIST := TYPE_LIST('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5');

SELECT A.NAME BULK COLLECT INTO CHILD_ITEMS 
FROM TABLE_A A, TABLE_B B WHERE A.ID = B.ITEM_ID;
```

Надо проверить, является ли `CHILD_ITEMS` подсписком `PARENT_ITEMS`, то есть, все элементы `CHILD_ITEMS` являются частью `PARENT_ITEMS`. Например:

- `CHILD_ITEMS` содержит `'item1','item2'` - условие вернёт `true`,
- а если содержит `'item1','item2','item100'`, то `false`, т.к. `'item100'` не являются частью `PARENT_ITEMS`.

Как написать `IF` условие в этом случае?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Check whether a list is sublist of another list in Oracle PL/SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67422401) от участника [@VGH](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492655/vgh)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/67422401

Answer (score 2):

Надо воспользоваться [SUBMULTISET](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html#GUID-6EC9172B-DF92-469B-B8BD-E7FFFCEFB37B) условием. Например:

```
declare 
    type itemList is table of varchar(8);
    childItems itemList  := itemList ('item2','item3','item4');
    parentItems itemList := itemList ('item1','item2','item3','item4','item5');
begin
    if childItems submultiset of parentItems then
        dbms_output.put_line ('is subset');
    else 
        dbms_output.put_line ('is not subset'); end if;
        
    childItems.extend;
    childItems(childItems.last) := 'item100';
    
    if childItems submultiset of parentItems then
        dbms_output.put_line ('is subset');
    else 
        dbms_output.put_line ('is not subset'); end if;
end;
/
```

> is subset
> is not subset