# При проверке на вхождение списка в другогой список, ошибка: PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to SUBMULTISET

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, коллекции

В [этом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1279055) показано как проверить условие, является ли список подсписком другого списка, при условии, что элементы списка - скалярные (или встроенные) типы данных.

Пробую с композитным типом данных, но получаю ошибку:

```
declare 
    type itemRec is record (id int, name varchar(8));
    type itemList is table of itemRec;
    childItems itemList  := itemList (itemRec(1,'item1'),itemRec(2,'item2'));
    parentItems itemList := itemList (itemRec(1,'item1'),itemRec(2,'item2'),itemRec(3,'item3'));
begin null;
    if childItems submultiset of parentItems then null; end if;
end;
/
```

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SUBMULTISET'

В документации к условию [SUBMULTISET](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Multiset-Conditions.html#GUID-6EC9172B-DF92-469B-B8BD-E7FFFCEFB37B) сказано, что элементы списков должны быть сравнимы:

> The element types of the nested table must be comparable. Refer to [Comparison Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Comparison-Conditions.html#GUID-828576BF-E606-4EA6-B94B-BFF48B67F927) for information on the comparability of nonscalar types.

И далее по ссылке:

> Two objects of nonscalar type are comparable if they are of the same named type and there is a one-to-one correspondence between their elements.

Но в примере выше ведь можно сравнить, что поля `id` и `name` равны?

Почему возникает эта ошибка и как её обойти?

---

PS В среде СУБД вместо *"список"* используется термин *"коллекция"*, но суть от этого не меняется...

Answer (score 3):

Переменные с типом данных - запись (`RECORD`) нельзя напрямую сравнить:

```
declare 
    type itemRec is record (id int, name varchar(8));
    rec1 itemRec := itemRec(1,'item1');
    rec2 itemRec := itemRec(1,'item1');
begin null;
    if rec1 = rec2 then null; end if;
end;
/
```

> PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to '='

Приведённые в вопросе цитаты касаются только типов данных известных в SQL, `RECORD` им не является. В подглаве [Record Comparisons](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-DFDE40BD-4B61-4C8A-B9CE-3FE01E21F658):

> Records cannot be tested natively for nullity, equality, or inequality. [...]
> You must write your own functions to implement such tests.

Можно конечно написать функцию, но она будет неизвестна условию `SUBMULTISET`.

Поэтому, решением будет, либо писать ещё одну фунцию с поэлементным сравнением в цикле, либо, что проще, воспользоваться обьектными типами, которые хорошо интегрированы в PL/SQL. Им тоже будет нужна функция для сравнения:

> nested tables of user-defined object types, even if their elements are comparable, **must have** MAP methods defined on them to be used in equality

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create or replace type itemRec force is object (id int, name varchar(8), map member function compare return varchar2)
/
create or replace type body itemRec as
    map member function compare return varchar2 is
    begin return to_char(id)||name;
    end;
end;
/
create or replace type itemList is table of itemRec;
/
declare 
    childItems itemList  := itemList (itemRec(1,'item1'),itemRec(2,'item2'));
    parentItems itemList := itemList (itemRec(1,'item1'),itemRec(2,'item2'),itemRec(3,'item3'));
    rec1 itemRec := itemRec(1,'item1');
    rec2 itemRec := itemRec(1,'item1');
begin
    if childItems submultiset of parentItems then
        dbms_output.put_line ('is subset');
    else 
        dbms_output.put_line ('is not subset'); end if;
        
    childItems.extend;
    childItems(childItems.last) := itemRec(9,'item9');
    
    if childItems submultiset of parentItems then
        dbms_output.put_line ('is subset');
    else 
        dbms_output.put_line ('is not subset'); end if;
end;
/
```

Результат:

> is subset
> is not subset